# Terraform Workspace - AWS provide - How to maintain different IAM Instance role / policy for each workspace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use Terraform workspace to build multiple environments in AWS.

Each environments has its own IAM instance role with different policy that need to be attached.

How do I enforce this in Terraform using Workspace.

**Terraform folder structure:**

```
ami.tf
backend.tf
iam_role_policy.tf
lauch_config.tf
local.tf
main.tf
output.tf
provider.tf
user_data.sh
variables.tf
```

**Terraform code:**

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_config" {
name_prefix                 = "${var.application_name}-${var.application_type}-${local.environment}-launch-config-"
image_id                    = "${data.aws_ami.puppet_ami.id}"
instance_type               = "${local.instance_type}"
security_groups             = "${var.security_group}"
key_name                    = "${local.key}"
user_data                   = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
iam_instance_profile        = "${aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_instance_role.name}"
associate_public_ip_address = false
}
```

I tried using `environment` folder structure that did not work

```
iam_instance_profile        = "${local.environment}/${aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_instance_role.name}"
```

Below is the error

```
terraform plan
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

Error: Reference to undeclared resource

  on lauch_config.tf line 23, in resource "aws_launch_configuration" "launch_config":
  23:     iam_instance_profile        = "${local.environment}/${aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_instance_role.name}"

A managed resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "iam_instance_role" has not been
declared in the root module.


Error: Reference to undeclared resource
```

Any thoughts on how to mitigate this issue?

Comment: You said that what you tried didn't work, but you didn't share what happened when you tried it. Could you share some more information about what happened, including any error messages you saw, exactly as they appeared?

Comment: @MartinAtkins updated the error in the Question, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: That error is saying you haven't defined a `aws_iam_instance_profile.iam_instance_role` resource. Can you share a [mcve] that exhibits your issues?

Comment: Just curious to know if there was a solution for this? I have a similar requirement - need to know if we can attach instance profile to workspace just like how we can do for EC2. Haven't tried through Terraform though.